# SPISettings was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino-uno, compile, wire-library

I'm trying to compile a simple I2C example to read data from an MPU-6050 accel/gyro sensor, but I'm getting the compilation error:

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:27:8: error: 'SPISettings' does not name a type
 static SPISettings settings;
        ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp: In member function 'void Sd2Card::chipSelectHigh()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:167:9: error: 'class SPIClass' has no member named 'endTransaction'
     SPI.endTransaction();
         ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp: In member function 'void Sd2Card::chipSelectLow()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:176:9: error: 'class SPIClass' has no member named 'beginTransaction'
     SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
         ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:176:26: error: 'settings' was not declared in this scope
     SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
                          ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t Sd2Card::init(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:269:3: error: 'settings' was not declared in this scope
   settings = SPISettings(250000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);
   ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:269:53: error: 'SPISettings' was not declared in this scope
   settings = SPISettings(250000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);
                                                     ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:275:7: error: 'class SPIClass' has no member named 'beginTransaction'
   SPI.beginTransaction(settings);
       ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:279:7: error: 'class SPIClass' has no member named 'endTransaction'
   SPI.endTransaction();
       ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t Sd2Card::setSckRate(uint8_t)':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:518:14: error: 'settings' was not declared in this scope
     case 0:  settings = SPISettings(25000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); break;
              ^
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp:518:66: error: 'SPISettings' was not declared in this scope
     case 0:  settings = SPISettings(25000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); break;
                                                                  ^
make: *** [.build_ano/uno/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.o] Error 1
Make failed with code 2
```

I've commented-out all code until it compiled without error, and I found that the error is caused by the line:

```
#include <Wire.h>
```

So my minimal code to reproduce the error is:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup(){
}

void loop(){
}
```

Why is this include throwing this error? Why is it trying to compile code for accessing an SD card when I have no code that uses that?

I'm using Arduino 1.6.1 and targeting the Uno. I found I can fix this error by copying version 1.0 of the Wire library into my local sketch folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fixed this by deleting this built-in library

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD
```

but then I received the error:

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Robot_Control/ArduinoRobot.cpp:25:2: error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope
  Serial1.begin(9600);
```

so I deleted these libraries as well:

```
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Robot_Control
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Robot_Motor
```

which appear to be buggy in the 1.6 Arduino release. It's still unclear why any of these libraries were being used, since I wasn't including any of their files.

Comment: Can you elaborate any further on this? I tried these steps and it still isn't working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try a later version of the IDE. Try making a completely new sketch (don't just delete things from your current one). It looks to me like it is trying to compile things it shouldn't.

> /usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.cpp

That doesn't seem relevant to your empty sketch.

Comment: Yes, it's strange, and yes, it's a completely new sketch.

Comment: If a sketch containing `#include <Wire.h>` and then `void setup(){} void loop(){}` doesn't compile there is something wrong with your installation. That should compile fine. Try IDE 1.6.8.